# How do I set the version info in a manifest file when building a netbeans project with jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins, jar, manifest.mf

I have a project built using the netbeans IDE (Internally uses Ant to build if I am not mistaken)

The CI server we use is jenkins.  I would like to add version info to the manifest for the jar that is produced.

How do I do that?

Comment: Please have a look. I added another example using an environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your Jenkins build process somehow update the project version a possible solution is:

in `nbproject\build-impl.xml` add an entry for the manifest

```
<target depends="init,-do-jar-create-manifest,-do-jar-copy-manifest" ...
    <manifest file="${tmp.manifest.file}" mode="update">
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
        <!-- add this line below -->
        <attribute name="Project-Version" value="${project.version}"/>
    </manifest>
</target>
```

in `nbproject\project.properties` add the project version

```
project.version=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

build

```
ant jar
```

output

```
$ unzip -p dist/CI-test.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | grep Project
Project-Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

**edit:** Another solution using an environment variable.

in `nbproject\build-impl.xml` add an entry for the manifest using the environment variable `PROJECT_VERSION`

```
<target depends="init,-do-jar-create-manifest,-do-jar-copy-manifest" ...
    <!-- enable access to environment variables -->
    <property environment="env"/>
    <manifest file="${tmp.manifest.file}" mode="update">
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
        <!-- add this line below -->
        <attribute name="Project-Version" value="${env.PROJECT_VERSION}"/>
    </manifest>
</target>
```

build

```
# define the environment variable
# on Windows use: set PROJECT_VERSION=0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
PROJECT_VERSION=0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
ant jar
```

output

```
$ unzip -p dist/CI-test.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | grep Project
Project-Version: 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
```